# My Windows Hook (and Direct Input) monitor does not receive events if certain apps in focus

Tags: c++, winapi

We have an application that can use either a Windows Hook (SetWindowsHookEx) or Direct Input to get keyboard events. We've noticed an interesting issue. If Mumble has focus, then my app will not receive any keyboard/mouse events (I can still read gamepad through Direct Input though). Has anyone else run into this issue before? We are trying to identify a logical reason why just merely giving the Mumble app focus would cause Windows not to notify my Windows Hook anymore. Looking through the source for Mumble, I do not see anything that stands out. It should not be suppressing events when the app has focus unless the user has intentionally bound a key with the suppress option.

I have searched all over the internet and cannot even find anyone else mention this issue. Below I am providing an example application to repro the issue. We are alarmed because we are concerned there might be other apps that interfere with our application.

```
// KeyHook.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

class KeyMonitorThread;
KeyMonitorThread* g_thread = NULL;

HHOOK m_keyboardHook;
HANDLE m_thread;
DWORD m_dwThreadId;
HWND m_window = NULL;
ATOM m_windowClass;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // todo....
    if (nCode < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(m_keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }


    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* key = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *>(lParam);

    return CallNextHookEx(m_keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto wc = WNDCLASS();
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"DirectInputMonitor";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    m_windowClass = RegisterClass(&wc);

    if (!m_windowClass)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    m_window = CreateWindow(
        reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(m_windowClass), // class name
        L"",       // window title
        0,         // style
        0,         // x
        0,         // y
        0,         // width
        0,         // height
        0,         // parent
        0,         // menu
        0,         // hinstance
        NULL       // param
    );

    m_keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);

    BOOL returnValue;
    MSG msg;
    while ((returnValue = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (returnValue == -1)
        {
             // handle the error and possibly exit
             break;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mumble might be a program that runs with UAC elevation.  You cannot spy on its keyboard input unless you run elevated as well.  Or it uses raw input, this site is filled with questions from people trying to cheat on their games.  Or it is the kind of program that actively defeats keyloggers, the worlds is filled with people that try to steal passwords.  Give the real name of "mumble" to get ahead.

Comment: Our program is similar to Mumble whereas we have Voice Chat. So we need to globally monitor keys when our app does not have focus. Was trying to sift through Mumble's source to see where they might be disable other keyloggers. That's an interesting thought they do this intentionally when their program has focus

Comment: Not really a c++ question. Make better tags. E.g., windows, directx?

Comment: First parameter in `CreateWindow` should be `wc.lpszClassName`, the cast used is meaningless (although this has nothing to do with whatever problem you are having, it just fails to create a fake window)

Comment: Since you already have an `HWND` anyway, you really should be using the [Raw Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) instead of a low-level keyboard hook. That way, the keyboard driver will send [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) messages directly to your window. Even the [`LowLevelKeybooardProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) documentation suggests this approach.

Comment: I'm assuming Raw Input would have the same issue. Currently both our Windows API (SetWindowsHookEx) and Direct Input implementations both suffer this bug where keyboard and mouse events are suppressed if Mumble is in focus. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant http://www.mumble.info/ it is a client-server voice chat program for group chats; cross-platform and open source. I was going to suggest that the OP look through the source but it seems they have already done so to no avail.

Comment: @sandboxgod you did not answer Hans's original question: is your setup running Mumble elevated? (I'm going to guess that you shouldn't be running it elevated, but I'm not aware of what your setup is.)